# How to NOT pull the given jar package every time when using maven

Tags: maven

In my project, these is a 3rd part jar. When i run 'mvn -U clean package', find this jar costs too much time to pull.
how can I set my pom file to void pull the jar every time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use the `-U` option since it:

> *Forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories*

See [Maven: The Complete Reference, 6.1. Maven Command Line Options.](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book//reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-deps-option) or `mvn --help`:

```
-U,--update-snapshots    Forces a check for missing
                         releases and updated snapshots on
                         remote repositories
```